# multibib: setting margins

Tags: margins, multibib

Using `multibib`, if  I define a bibliography entitled "Primary literature" by using the following line:

```
\newcites{prim}{Primary Literature}
```

and then I write into the `document` block:

```
\nociteprim{ref1,ref2}
\bibliographystyleprim{apacite}
\bibliographyprim{publications}   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
```

I obtain the list of bib entries, e.g.:

```
Primary literature
entry1
entry2
....
```

How can I set a left margin to the sole entries, e.g.

```
Primary literature
      entry1
      entry2
      ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading `apacite` and `multibib`, you could execute the commands

```
\setlength{\bibleftmargin}{0em}
\setlength{\bibindent}{2em}
```

to get the first line of every entry to be indented by `2em` relative to any further lines. The amount of indentation of the remaining lines with respect to the left hand edge of the text block is governed by `\bibleftmargin`.

How to modify some of these parameters is explained in the manual of the `apacite` package.